# How to generate an excel file using Cordova and VueJs?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, vue.js, xlsx

I'm using Cordova and VueJs to build an android application. In my app I need to generate an excel file, for this reason, I used XLSX package, it works on my desktop and a save dialog is showing up. but it doesn't work on my android device and nothing showing up. also I have no error!

OS: Linux Mint 19

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "cordova-pdf-generator": "^2.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-persian-datetime-picker": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.27",
    "vuesax": "^3.10.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-cordova": "^2.3.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

My function:

```
   generateExcel: function (item, fileName, fileData) {
    try {
      if (item.noe_hozeh) {
        var animalWS = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.Datas.animals)
        var pokemonWS = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.Datas.pokemons)
        var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new() // make Workbook of Excel
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, animalWS, 'animals') // sheetAName is name of Worksheet
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, pokemonWS, 'pokemons')
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'Item-' + item.noe_hozeh + '-' + item.date + '.xlsx') // name of the file is '*.xlsx'
       } else {
        this.$toasted.show('Some message', {
          duration: 2000,
          type: 'error'
        })
      }
    } catch (e) {
       this.$toasted.show(e, {
          duration: 2000,
          type: 'error'
        })
      console.log(e)
      alert('error')
    }
  }
```

It would be great to help me to generate the Excel file on my Android device.
Thank you